# How to create a paper organization chart in Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, forest

I want to create a paper organization chart like this image.[image] If anyone could help me, it will be a great help.
Thank you.

Comment: Please add some code showing what you have tried so far, and idenfity the parts that are causing you problems

Comment: Unfortunately, I am a novice with tikZ, and found it very difficult to understand in a short time. I am seeking help from, who have expertise in drawing. Thank you @IanThompson

Comment: Did you search for keywords like `tree` or `forest`? You should get tons of example that fullfill your needs. Drawing it by hand in Ti*k*Z is definitely not a valuable solution, especially if you just need to move some part of your tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I could do so far using `tikz`. Your question is is straitforward, so just have a look at the manual and try to understand the syntax. Maybe there is an easier way defining the arrows.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{%
    every node/.style={draw=blue, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, fill=blue!50}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        %first row
        
        \node (1) at (0,0) {\textcolor{white}{1. Introduction}};
        \node[anchor=west] (2) at ($(1.east)+(1cm,0)$) {\textcolor{white}{1. Introduction}};
        \node[anchor=west] (3) at ($(2.east)+(1cm,0)$) {\textcolor{white}{1. Introduction}};
        \node[anchor=west] (4) at ($(3.east)+(1cm,0)$) {\textcolor{white}{1. Introduction}};
        \node[anchor=west] (5) at ($(4.east)+(1cm,0)$) {\textcolor{white}{1. Introduction}};
        \node[anchor=west] (6) at ($(5.east)+(1cm,0)$) {\textcolor{white}{1. Introduction}};
        
        %arrows
        
        \draw[-stealth, blue!50] (1.east) -- (2.west);
        \draw[-stealth, blue!50] (2.east) -- (3.west);
        \draw[-stealth, blue!50] (3.east) -- (4.west);
        \draw[-stealth, blue!50] (4.east) -- (5.west);
        \draw[-stealth, blue!50] (5.east) -- (6.west);
        
        %first column
        
        \node[anchor=north] (7) at ($(1.south)+(0.5cm,-0.5cm)$) {\textcolor{white}{1. Introduction}};
        
        \draw[-stealth, blue!50] ($(1.south west)+(0.25cm,0)$) -- ($(1.south west)+(0.25cm,0)+(0,-1cm-\pgflinewidth/2)$) -- (7.west);
        
        %second column
        
        \node[anchor=north] (8) at ($(2.south)+(0.5cm,-0.5cm)$) {\textcolor{white}{1. Introduction}};
        \node[anchor=north] (9) at ($(8.south)+(0,-0.5cm)$) {\textcolor{white}{1. Introduction}};
        \node[anchor=north] (10) at ($(9.south)+(0,-0.5cm)$) {\textcolor{white}{1. Introduction}};
        \node[anchor=north] (11) at ($(10.south)+(0,-0.5cm)$) {\textcolor{white}{1. Introduction}};
        
        \draw[-stealth, blue!50] ($(2.south west)+(0.25cm,0)$) -- ($(2.south west)+(0.25cm,0)+(0,-1cm-\pgflinewidth/2)$) -- (8.west);
        \draw[-stealth, blue!50] ($(8.west)+(-0.25cm,0)$) -- ($(8.west)+(-0.25cm,-1.5cm-\pgflinewidth)$) -- (9.west);
        \draw[-stealth, blue!50] ($(9.west)+(-0.25cm,0)$) -- ($(9.west)+(-0.25cm,-1.5cm-\pgflinewidth)$) -- (10.west);
        \draw[-stealth, blue!50] ($(10.west)+(-0.25cm,0)$) -- ($(10.west)+(-0.25cm,-1.5cm-\pgflinewidth)$) -- (11.west);
        
        %third column
        
        \node[anchor=north] (12) at ($(3.south)+(0.5cm,-0.5cm)$) {\textcolor{white}{1. Introduction}};
        \node[anchor=north] (13) at ($(12.south)+(0,-0.5cm)$) {\textcolor{white}{1. Introduction}};
        
        \draw[-stealth, blue!50] ($(3.south west)+(0.25cm,0)$) -- ($(3.south west)+(0.25cm,0)+(0,-1cm-\pgflinewidth/2)$) -- (12.west);
        \draw[-stealth, blue!50] ($(12.west)+(-0.25cm,0)$) -- ($(12.west)+(-0.25cm,-1.5cm-\pgflinewidth)$) -- (13.west);
        
        %forth column
        
        \node[anchor=north] (14) at ($(4.south)+(0.5cm,-0.5cm)$) {\textcolor{white}{1. Introduction}};
        \node[anchor=north] (15) at ($(14.south)+(0,-0.5cm)$) {\textcolor{white}{1. Introduction}};
        
        \draw[-stealth, blue!50] ($(4.south west)+(0.25cm,0)$) -- ($(4.south west)+(0.25cm,0)+(0,-1cm-\pgflinewidth/2)$) -- (14.west);
        \draw[-stealth, blue!50] ($(14.west)+(-0.25cm,0)$) -- ($(14.west)+(-0.25cm,-1.5cm-\pgflinewidth)$) -- (15.west);
        
        %fifth column
        
        \node[anchor=north] (16) at ($(5.south)+(0.5cm,-0.5cm)$) {\textcolor{white}{1. Introduction}};
        \node[anchor=north] (17) at ($(16.south)+(0,-0.5cm)$) {\textcolor{white}{1. Introduction}};
        
        \draw[-stealth, blue!50] ($(5.south west)+(0.25cm,0)$) -- ($(5.south west)+(0.25cm,0)+(0,-1cm-\pgflinewidth/2)$) -- (16.west);
        \draw[-stealth, blue!50] ($(16.west)+(-0.25cm,0)$) -- ($(16.west)+(-0.25cm,-1.5cm-\pgflinewidth)$) -- (17.west);
        
        %sixth column
        
        \node[anchor=north] (18) at ($(6.south)+(0.5cm,-0.5cm)$) {\textcolor{white}{1. Introduction}};
        
        \draw[-stealth, blue!50] ($(6.south west)+(0.25cm,0)$) -- ($(6.south west)+(0.25cm,0)+(0,-1cm-\pgflinewidth/2)$) -- (18.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If there are any further questions, we will try to help.

**EDIT**

I simplified the syntax for the `arrows` and added the correct labels.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{blueframe}{RGB}{48,84,151}
\definecolor{bluefill}{RGB}{70,114,196}

\def\shifta{2cm}
\def\shiftb{1cm}

\tikzset{%
    every node/.style={draw=blueframe, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=1cm, fill=bluefill},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        %first row
        
        \node (1) at (0,0) {\textcolor{white}{1. Introduction}};
        \node[anchor=west] (2) at ($(1.east)+(\shifta,0)$) {\textcolor{white}{2. Related Works}};
        \node[anchor=west] (3) at ($(2.east)+(\shifta,0)$) {\textcolor{white}{3. Experimental Setup}};
        \node[anchor=west] (4) at ($(3.east)+(\shifta,0)$) {\textcolor{white}{4. Proposed Model}};
        \node[anchor=west] (5) at ($(4.east)+(\shifta,0)$) {\textcolor{white}{5. Results and Discussion}};
        \node[anchor=west] (6) at ($(5.east)+(\shifta,0)$) {\textcolor{white}{6. Conclusion}};
        
        %arrows
        
        \draw[-stealth, blueframe] (1.east) -- (2.west);
        \draw[-stealth, blueframe] (2.east) -- (3.west);
        \draw[-stealth, blueframe] (3.east) -- (4.west);
        \draw[-stealth, blueframe] (4.east) -- (5.west);
        \draw[-stealth, blueframe] (5.east) -- (6.west);
        
        %first column
        
        \node[anchor=north] (7) at ($(1.south)+(\shiftb,-\shiftb)$) {\textcolor{white}{dummy text}};
        
        \coordinate (1a) at ($(1.south west)+(\shiftb/2,0)$);
        
        \draw[-stealth, blueframe] (1a) |- (7.west);
        
        %second column
        
        \node[anchor=north] (8) at ($(2.south)+(\shiftb,-\shiftb)$) {\textcolor{white}{dummy text}};
        \node[anchor=north] (9) at ($(8.south)+(0,-\shiftb)$) {\textcolor{white}{dummy text}};
        \node[anchor=north] (10) at ($(9.south)+(0,-\shiftb)$) {\textcolor{white}{dummy text}};
        \node[anchor=north] (11) at ($(10.south)+(0,-\shiftb)$) {\textcolor{white}{dummy text}};
        
        \coordinate (2a) at ($(2.south west)+(\shiftb/2,0)$);
        
        \draw[-stealth, blueframe] (2a) |- (8.west);
        \draw[-stealth, blueframe] (2a) |- (9.west);
        \draw[-stealth, blueframe] (2a) |- (10.west);
        \draw[-stealth, blueframe] (2a) |- (11.west);
                
        %third column
        
        \node[anchor=north] (12) at ($(3.south)+(\shiftb,-\shiftb)$) {\textcolor{white}{dummy text}};
        \node[anchor=north] (13) at ($(12.south)+(0,-\shiftb)$) {\textcolor{white}{dummy text}};
        
        \coordinate (3a) at ($(3.south west)+(\shiftb/2,0)$);
        
        \draw[[-stealth, blueframe] (3a) |- (12.west);
        \draw[[-stealth, blueframe] (3a) |- (13.west);
                
        %forth column
        
        \node[anchor=north] (14) at ($(4.south)+(\shiftb,-\shiftb)$) {\textcolor{white}{dummy text}};
        \node[anchor=north] (15) at ($(14.south)+(0,-\shiftb)$) {\textcolor{white}{dummy text}};
        
        \coordinate (4a) at ($(4.south west)+(\shiftb/2,0)$);
        
        \draw[-stealth, blueframe] (4a) |- (14.west);
        \draw[-stealth, blueframe] (4a) |- (15.west);
        
        %fifth column
        
        \node[anchor=north] (16) at ($(5.south)+(\shiftb,-\shiftb)$) {\textcolor{white}{dummy text}};
        \node[anchor=north] (17) at ($(16.south)+(0,-\shiftb)$) {\textcolor{white}{dummy text}};
        
        \coordinate (5a) at ($(5.south west)+(\shiftb/2,0)$);
        
        \draw[-stealth, blueframe] (5a) |- (16.west);
        \draw[-stealth, blueframe] (5a) |- (17.west);
        
        %sixth column
        
        \node[anchor=north] (18) at ($(6.south)+(\shiftb,-\shiftb)$) {\textcolor{white}{dummy text}};
        
        \coordinate (6a) at ($(6.south west)+(\shiftb/2,0)$);
        
        \draw[-stealth, blueframe] (6a) |- (18.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Excelsior Appreciated, all of your efforts